# I am getting unsupported parameter combination CGBitmap error with swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cgcontext, cgbitmapcontext

I am trying to create a CGContext in swift. It compiles but throws an error at runtime.

```
let colorSpace:CGColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let context:CGContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, 20, 20, 8, 0, colorSpace, CGBitmapInfo.AlphaInfoMask)
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

....
```

And the error is:

```
Error: CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: 8 integer bits/component; 32 bits/pixel; 3-component color space; unrecognized; 96 bytes/row.
fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Just in case somebody is running into the same problem. The snippet below finally works.

```
let colorSpace:CGColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)
let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, UInt(rect.size.width), UInt(rect.size.height), 8, 0, colorSpace, bitmapInfo)
```

It generates a 32 bit RGBA context in swift

Comment: With the current version of Swift (I'm using Xcode 6.1):

let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)

Comment: And with the current version of the Xcode is  now:
 let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, Int(rect.size.width), Int(rect.size.height), 8, 0, colorSpace, bitmapInfo)

Comment: Swift 2.0 actually expects a `UInt32` instead of a `CGBitMapInfo` object, so in Swift 2.0 use `let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, Int(rect.size.width), Int(rect.size.height), 8, 0, colorSpace, bitmapInfo.rawValue)`. <- notice how we convert `CGBitMapInfo` to `UInt32` by using its `rawValue`

Comment: Swift 2 let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colourSpace, CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Little.rawValue)

Comment: I want to use other that PremultipliedLast but if I am using none, first or last context become nil

Answer (score 18):

Updated for Swift 3:

```
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)
    guard let context = CGContext.init(data: nil, width: Int(size.width), height: Int(size.height), bitsPerComponent: Int(bitsPerComponent), bytesPerRow: Int(bytesPerRow), space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: UInt32(bitmapInfo.rawValue)) else {
        // cannot create context - handle error
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

In Swift 2.1 one can access the fields properly, and even OR them together:

```
let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Little.rawValue)

let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8,
                bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo.rawValue);
```

Whole lot of 'rawValue' going on :)

You don't even need to separate out the bitmapInfo, and can do a one-liner:

```
let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8,
                bytesPerRow, colorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Little.rawValue
```

Answer (score 6):

Updated for **Swift 5**:

```
 let colorSpace:CGColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
 let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)
 let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: UInt(rect.size.width), height: UInt(rect.size.height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 0, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)
```

where rect has height and width

Comment: "CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue". Really, Apple?

Answer (score 4):

I had some issues in Swift 1.2 using `UInt`, now I'm using `Int` and it's working.
This Example shows how to convert an Image to a grayscale image.

```
let imageRect = self.myImage.frame

let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
let width = imageRect.width
let height = imageRect.height

let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.None.rawValue)
let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, Int(width), Int(height), 8, 0, colorSpace, bitmapInfo)
```

Answer (score 4):

Suggested way compatible with both **Xcode 8.3** and **Xcode 9** which supports **Swift 3** and **Swift 4**

```
let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
guard let bitmapContext = CGContext(data: nil, 
                                    width: Int(size.width),
                                    height: Int(size.height),
                                    bitsPerComponent: Int(bitsPerComponent),
                                    bytesPerRow: Int(bytesPerRow),
                                    space: colorSpace,
                                    bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue) else {
                                  return nil
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 2.2:

```
let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue).rawValue
let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, Int(width), Int(height), 8, 0, colorSpace, bitmapInfo)
```

Answer (score 0):

CGBitmapInfo.AlphaInfoMask is not a valid bitmap info.

Try setting CGBitmapInfo.AlphaLast or CGBitmapInfo.AlphaFirst.

Comment: This does not compile and i can not find CGBitmapInfo.AlphaLast or CGBitmapInfo.AlphaFirst in https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGBitmapContextCreate