# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'CGBitmapInfo' with an argument list of type '(UInt32)'

Tags: ios, swift2, metal

I am add an image as a texture to a sphere in metal. using swift 2.0, but I got a error CGBitmapInfo(options), it said: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'CGBitmapInfo' with an argument list of type '(UInt32)'...Anybody knows how to fix it? Here is my code:

```
func textureForImage(image:UIImage, device:MTLDevice) -> MTLTexture?
{
    let imageRef = image.CGImage

    let width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef)
    let height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef)
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

    let rawData = calloc(height * width * 4, sizeof(UInt8))

    let bytesPerPixel = 4
    let bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width
    let bitsPerComponent = 8

    let options = CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Big.rawValue

    let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData,
                                        width,
                                        height,
                                        bitsPerComponent,
                                        bytesPerRow,
                                        colorSpace,
                                        CGBitmapInfo(options))


    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(width), CGFloat(height)), imageRef)

    let textureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat(.RGBA8Unorm,
                                                                                    width: Int(width),
                                                                                    height: Int(height),
                                                                                    mipmapped: true)
    let texture = device.newTextureWithDescriptor(textureDescriptor)

    let region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, Int(width), Int(height))

    texture.replaceRegion(region,
                          mipmapLevel: 0,
                          slice: 0,
                          withBytes: rawData,
                          bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,
                          bytesPerImage: bytesPerRow * height)

    free(rawData)

    return texture
}
```

Comment: Check this out- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109149/cgbitmapcontextcreate-error-with-swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current version of Swift, the final parameter of `CGBitmapContextCreate` is a `UInt32`, so in place of `CGBitmapInfo(options)` above, you should just pass `options` (the expression assigned to `options` is inferred to have type `UInt32`).

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad it's been well-received.